# Send sms automatically for incoming calls and messages

Tags: android, sms, phone-call

I'm a UG student.....I'm creating an android application as my project work
My application is......setting an event in calender....my app retrieves start time and end time from calender and silences the calls and messages received during that time period and sends sms to calls and messages automatically if required....i have coded till the silencing calls and messages..and I have kept the check boxes to reply for calls and to reply for sms but I'm not understanding how to send messages if the user selects the check boxes

Answer (score 0):

- you can store the user preferences in a database (or shared preferences, or [any other way](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)), on the basis of the checkbox
- check for the preferences, whenever an event for which you could send a message occurs and send a message programmatically with the following code

  ```
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
      try
      {
          sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, messageText, null, null);
      }
      catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
      {

      }
  ```